# How can I possibly know if a tag is deprecated or not?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tagging, tag-wiki

How can I possibly know if a tag is deprecated or not?

I see several people at "electrical engineering meta" mention that some tag or another is [now deprecated](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=deprecated).

I can't seem to figure out which tags are or are not deprecated, so I suspect lots of other people also have difficulty finding out this information.

I looked at the FAQ page, the about page (linked at the top of every page on the site), and the "tag-wiki" page about the tag that you end up at when you click on the tag, and I haven't found any information about specific tags -- in particular, the [homework](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag -- being deprecated.

Is there a list of deprecated questions somewhere -- perhaps carefully typed up and filed in a filing cabinet in the basement of some building on a nearby planet?(1)

So is there (a) some some super-obvious link to this information that I am overlooking, or (b) does this site need an extra feature, that gives information on which tags are deprecated and why?

(1): *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*

Comment: a short list of tags that are deprecated are tags that are are attempting to purge, at which point they will not exist in the system. A discussion of some of the major ones exists [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/822/shouldnt-we-disallow-adding-deprecated-tags).

Comment: If a tag is depreciated, that could easily be noted in the short info section of the tag wiki...

Comment: @W5VO, if we remove the tag the wiki will no longer exist, as it should not. Makes adding a note on the wiki less productive then just posting to remove it.

Comment: @Kortuk: is there a difference between "posting to remove it" and "removing it without warning"?

Comment: @davidcary, we have to post to get a developer from SE to remove the tag. If there are only a couple cases of the tag, we can do it by edits.

Answer (score 4):

Generally this should be indicated in the tag wiki itself.

If the tag has many instances -- so many that removing them by hand is onerous -- contact the Stack Exchange team and we can remove such unwanted tags "behind the scenes" without bumping, etc.